# JavaScript from MSDN won't work (error: unexpected response from server)

Tags: 2013, javascript, sharepoint-server

I used the code from "[How to: Complete basic operations using JavaScript library code in SharePoint 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj163201.aspx)", the part underneath "SharePoint website tasks".

I'll just paste the code here, so that you can see it without having to open the above site:

```
 function retrieveWebSite(siteUrl) {
    var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
    this.oWebsite = clientContext.get_web();

    clientContext.load(this.oWebsite);

    clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQuerySucceeded), 
        Function.createDelegate(this, this.onQueryFailed)
    );
}

function onQuerySucceeded(sender, args) {
    alert('Title: ' + this.oWebsite.get_title() + 
        ' Description: ' + this.oWebsite.get_description());
}

function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
    alert('Request failed. ' + args.get_message() + 
        '\nStackTrace: ' + args.get_stackTrace());
}
```

Whenever I run it, I get the following error:

> Request failed. Unexpected response from server. StackTrace: null

I am absolutely clueless on why it won't work. I even tried adding the code below at the top of the script (which I collected from browsing other questions here), in the hopes that it would help. But alas. Even that won't do it.

```
SP.SOD.executeOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded('SP.UserProfiles.js', "~sitecollection/Style%20Library/Scripts/jquery.SPServices-2013.01.min.js");
SP.SOD.executeFunc('SP.js', 'SP.ClientContext');
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(retrieveWebSite, "sp.js"); });
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

This is the code I use to loop through all elements in the quick launch navigation (it is a term driven navigation), as soon as it encounters an element that has a href attribute ending with "Virtual-desk.aspx", it launches the function retrieveWebsiteUrl(). So basically with this code I give a value to the siteUrl variable. The function runMe() is called as soon as the document is ready.

```
$(document).ready(function () { ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(runMe, "sp.js"); });

var siteUrl = '';
var counter = 0;
var clientContext;

function runMe() {
    var $this = $("#NavRootAspMenu"); 
    if($this != null) {
        $this.find('li').each(function(i){
            counter = counter + 1;  
            siteUrl = $this.find("a.static")[i].href;
            console.log('List item found, count = ' + counter + '; ---------- ' + siteUrl); 
            if (siteUrl.indexOf('Virtual-desk.aspx') > -1) {
                console.log('Encountered the page "Virtual-desk.aspx". Now running retrieveWebSite().');
                retrieveWebSite(siteUrl);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the value of oWebsite ?

Comment: I am having same issue. Did you get any solution?

Comment: Did you found any solution to above ?? Please let me know if you have any solution. Thanks. -Pethuraj.

Answer (score 1):

What is the value of the `siteUrl` variable? Ideally it should be a url to the site you are trying to open.

Or if you want to open the current site, you can do:

```
var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
```

Comment: I'll add code to my original question to explain how I fetch the value of the siteUrl.

Comment: If I use `SP.ClientContext.get_current()` instead of `SP.ClientContext(siteUrl)`, it will only return the url of the page the user is currently on. I need it to work with 'SP.ClientContext(siteUrl)` because I'm looping through a list of urls.